# Android: programmatically rotate dialog

Tags: android, rotation, device

How to programmatically rotate dialog box?

I have an activity that is set to portrait mode with:

```
<activity
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Is there a way to pop up a Dialog depending on device orientation? 
On iPhone it's possible to both detect device orientation and manually rotate any object to that orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialog's follow the orientation of the activity behind it, so if that activity is set to portrait, then the dialog gets stuck with that preference too.

I'm not sure this will work, but you could try implementing your own transparent activity without the screenOrientation preference and shoving a dialog in that.